# How to fetch an API in NextJS from the api folder

Tags: api, next.js

I created an API with NextJS in the API folder. Now I want to fetch the data from that API in the getServerSideProps function.

```
const res = await fetch(`localhost:3000/api/playlist`);
```

But I get an error that says that it only supports HTTPS protocols.

```
Server Error

TypeError: Only HTTP(S) protocols are supported
This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
```

How can I fetch the data from the NextJS API on my localhost?
Thanks for you helping out!

Comment: just `fetch('/api/playlist')`

Comment: @NikitaMazur Unfortunately that's not working, I get a TypeError -> TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported

Comment: can you share the code please?

Comment: @NikitaMazur I found the problem, I forgot to write "http://". Thank you anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem, I forgot to add *http://* in front of the URL.

The code would then look like this:

```
const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/playlist`);
```

Comment: Is it the right way to fetch the data from the route handler?

Comment: I guess this should be dynamic depends on the mode ( dev, prod).